# What are the class naming conventions for blender?

Tags: python, add-on

I've recently searching about drawing template lists and find this question:
 [Populate a list with custom property dictionary data](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15917/populate-a-list-with-custom-property-dictionary-data)
 but a thing that caught my atention was the name for the class "OBJECT_ul_zones" it remenbed others name I have seen with the same pattern: "TYPE_Class_classname" like OBJECT_OT_someoperator

Then came the question: what are the naming conventions for class and variables in Blender?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of strict class naming is more prevalent within blenders source code than within third party addons. While CamelCase is common I don't think there is a strong convention for class names, however, the name used in `bl_idname` is visible and used within blender so does have some conventions, with a view to also help prevent naming clashes.

For a [panel](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Panel.html) the convention is `CATEGORY_PT_name` and if not set will be the class name. Similarly, [menus](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Menu.html) use `CATEGORY_MT_name`. Common categories are Object, Mesh and Material. Both of these can often be found duplicated into class names, often using class names instead of setting `bl_idname`. Within blender's builtin operators you will find most use this naming (with `CAT_OT_name`) for operator classes. There are also examples of `CAT_UL_name` used for [UILists](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UIList.html).

For an [operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html), the `bl_idname` **must** be two words separated by a `.`, the first word should be a category while the second is the operator name. Operator `bl_idnames` are added to `bpy.ops` so if you have `bl_idname='mesh.beautify'` then the operator can be called from python with `bpy.ops.mesh.beautify()` and is added to a panel with `layout.operator('mesh.beautify')`.

Comment: https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/class-naming-conventions-in-blender-2-8-python-api/